# Where is state coming from in this @reduxjs/toolkit module?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  items: [],
};

export const basketSlice = createSlice({
  name: "basket",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    // actions & reducers; actions named same as reducers in redux toolkit
    addToBasket: (state, action) => {
      state.items = [...state.items, action.payload];
    },
    removeFromBasket: (state, action) => {
      const index = state.items.findIndex(
        (basketItem) => action.payload.id === basketItem.id
      );

      let newBasket = [...state.items];

      if (index >= 0) {
        // item exists in the basket; remove it
        newBasket.splice(index, 1);
      } else {
        // else the item doesn't exist
        console.warn(
          `Can't remove product (id: ${action.payload.id}) as it's not in the basket.`
        );
      }

      state.items = newBasket;
    },
  },
});

export const { addToBasket, removeFromBasket } = basketSlice.actions;
export const basketActions = basketSlice.actions;

export const selectItems = (state) => state.basket.items;
export const selectTotal = (state) =>
  state.basket.items.reduce((total, item) => total + item.price, 0);

export default basketSlice.reducer;
```

Where is the passed in "state" variable coming from? I don't understand how this works. A function is being returned here and React is injecting the state as the first argument? But since I'm defining the function, how does React know to do this?

Does every returned function have state as the first property? But even then, I don't understand how this will work as state is coming from the above basketSlice.

Answer (score 0):

I see, the function declaration has access to the global state, meaning all slices.

In this example we're getting the basket state via the state.basket reference and the function declaration is just a helper/wrapper function that doesn't need to even be in the basketSlice module.

I tried the following in another module and it works well.

```
  const items = useSelector((state) => state.basket.items);
```

Now I understand.